# Not getting the Laravel foreign key table [ERROR]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this function in the Controller:

```
  /**
    *
    * Edit Registration
    *
    */
    public function edit(Registration $id)
    {
      $logs = Log::where('registration_id', $id->id)->users()->get();

      dd($logs);
      return view('registrations_edit', ['registration' => $id, 'log' => $logs]);
    }
```

The documentation says I can call

```
Log::where('registration_id', $id->id)->users()->get();
```

when I define `users()` in the Model.

```
 public function users(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
 }
```

but when I call `users()` in the Controller i always get

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::users()

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: try User::class instead of User:class

Comment: i tried it as you say but getting still the same error. 

I now changed it to App\User like in the documentation. But still getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this :

```
public function edit(Registration $id)
    {
      $logs = Log::with('users')->where('registration_id', $id->id)->get();

      dd($logs);
      return view('registrations_edit', ['registration' => $id, 'log' => $logs]);
    }
```

Hope this work for you

Comment: that worked for me thanks!
Can you tell me what that with() does? 
I can't find this method in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

If your relations write in right way, try this:

```
$logs = Log::where('registration_id', $id->id)->users->get();
```

Comment: When i try this i get 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$users